# Cant add background image to CSS button

Tags: css, button, styling

Just started with styling buttons and my desire was to have a background to the left of the button while the text search was to the right of the image.
Heres the code I have so far. [And here is how the button is so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2ytt.png)

How can I add a small icon to the left of the text? I tried running this code but no luck.

```
background: no-repeat url("http://www.veryicon.com/icon/ico/System/Small%20%26%20Flat/beer.ico") 0 0;
```

```css
.button {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    text-indent:76px;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#666666;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:66px;
    line-height:66px;
    width:152px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}
.button:hover {
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100%);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100%);
    background-color:#e9e9e9;
}
.button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Search!</div>
```

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with Java programming. Could you be meaning Javascript? If so, change your question tags as you are likely attracting the wrong experts to your question.

Comment: Apologize, didnt see I added java lol

Comment: ico? As I know, you cant add a ico, browsers doesn't support this format. If you just want  to add an icon, you can use bootstrap's glyphicons, simple and effective.

Comment: I shall be using a different image, that is just example code of what I attempted. The image I plan on using is jpg or png ending. Sorry forgot to point it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding your exact code to the example code output works, so there's something wrong with the way you incorporated the line into your css definitions.

Unfortunately, your example code doesn't include the actual line, but my guess is that you might have put it above the linear-gradient background definitions, which would then override your image. To test if this is the error, put it all the way at the bottom of the .button declaration and see if it's being displayed.

To use multiple background images, you can comma-seperate the individual values, like so:

```
background-image: url('one.png'), url('two.jpg');
background-position: center center, left top;
```

Comment: @Jonathan: Glad I could help! Also, if this or any answer has solved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself - though there is no obligation to do this

Answer (score 0):

Try to give background-size property like this

```css
.button {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  text-indent: 76px;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #666666;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  height: 66px;
  line-height: 66px;
  width: 152px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
  background: no-repeat url("http://www.veryicon.com/icon/ico/System/Small%20%26%20Flat/beer.ico") 0 0;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="button">Search!</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I attempted your suggestion but I am having no luck

Comment: I tried & it works for me, I edited the answer with my complete code.

Comment: EDIT* sorry about that I inputed it incorrectly and just realized comparing both codes where my mistake was. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your background image after background linear gradient

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple backgrounds to an element, you need to declare them all in a comma-separated list, like this:

```css
.button {
    background: no-repeat url("http://www.veryicon.com/icon/ico/System/Small%20%26%20Flat/beer.ico") 0 0, linear-gradient(to bottom, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
}
```

Backgrounds are painted from last to first, so your icon should show up just fine.

If you declare a property multiple times, the browser will really overwrite the previous value, unless the new one is invalid. Also, keep in mind that gradients are considered "images".

Comment: Thank you very helpful !